# wsdl2java client stubs for only some operations supported by the wsdl?

Tags: wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java, xmlbeans

Using Axis2 Wsdl2Java: is there a way to generate the relevant client code from a wsdl, but only for a subset of the supported operations in the wsdl that are of interest.

i.e. if the wsdl has say a hundered operations is it possble to only generate client stub code for one or two of the operations that are of interest?

I have generated client stubs for a customers WSDL and the resulting generated stubs and supporting code is far too large for my purposes > 75MB.

I have used Axis2 Wsdl2Java with the -U option to unpack the binding, and due to parse errors when trying with ADB I had to use XML beans binding also.

Thanks,

> > As I have not received much feedback on this: I am going to edit this to restate the problem, (as I don't really care how the solution is arrived at).

Basically my real issue is that I am generating a rather large WAR file that is using the client in Tomcat7.0 and It is consuming large amounts of memory.

Perhaps, I don't need to/shouldn't bundle all the generated  classes in the WAR. but it looks to me that these are integral to the Stub generated,and I am sure there is a more elegant solution than me picking bits out manually?

So I guess to restate the problem another way: Axis2 is generating a very large WAR file that is consuming a large amount of my Tomcat resources. How can I scale down this WAR to be smaller/"more light weight" WAR.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same issue, although I'm using the wsimport tool to generate stubs. Specifically, I want to generate stubs for this wsdl http://www.daytonfreight.com/WebServices_v1.1/ShippingService.asmx?WSDL, but I only want to generate stubs for the operations pertaining to "pickups".

Thus far, my only solution has been to generate stubs for all operations and then strip out the classes / code that I don't need.